# In this html/jquery slideshow, how can I make it stop on last image?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I know very little about coding with JavaScript/HTML. I have this html file which is a slideshow using a .js file, but the html file dictates how it's run. It grabs a folder of images then displays them one after another in a loop, but I want it to stop on the last slide. How can I make that happen?

I have tried googling, but was not able to find anything useful, because I am not skilled enough.

```js
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  //console.log(a);
  return a;
}

// [0, max)
function randomizeTick(max) {
  tick = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

// setup image src strings
let images = imageNamesStr.split("\n");
images.shift();
images.pop();
for (let i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // remove js, sh, or directory
  let remove = images[i].includes(".js") || images[i].includes(".sh") || !images[i].includes(".") || images[i].includes(".git");
  if (remove) {
    images.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

// setup indexes for shuffling
let indexes = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i] = "images/" + images[i];
  indexes.push(i);
}

// init img elements
let topImage = document.createElement("img");
let botImage = document.createElement("img");
let imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
imageContainer.appendChild(topImage);
imageContainer.appendChild(botImage);
topImage.id = "topImage";
botImage.id = "botImage";

// prevent white outline by setting initial transparency
topImage.style.opacity = "0.0";
botImage.style.opacity = "0.0";

//set init image
let tick = 0;
if (mode === 0) {
  shuffle(indexes);
}

//randomize tick
if (mode === 2) {
  randomizeTick(images.length);
}

let fadeDuration = slideDuration * 0.25;

function slideshow() {
  //let fadeDuration = 500;

  $("#botImage").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  }, {
    duration: fadeDuration
  });

  $("#topImage").animate({ //properties
    opacity: 0
  }, { //options
    duration: fadeDuration,
    done: function() {
      if (tick === images.length - 1) { //reset
        if (mode === 0) {
          shuffle(indexes);
        } else if (mode === 2) {
          randomizeTick(images.length);
        }
        tick = 0;
      } else {
        tick++;
      }

      topImage.src = botImage.src;
      topImage.style.opacity = "1.0";
      botImage.src = images[indexes[tick]];
      botImage.style.opacity = "0.0";
    }
  });
}

if (images.length > 0) {
  botImage.src = images[indexes[tick]];
  botImage.style.opacity = "0.0";

  //initial fade in
  $("#botImage").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  }, {
    duration: fadeDuration
  });

  $("#topImage").animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    duration: fadeDuration
  });

  if (images.length > 1) {
    slideshow();
    setInterval(slideshow, slideDuration);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-color: transparent;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imageContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I think changing `images.length > 1` to `images.length > 2` at the bottom should do what you want

Comment: @Mucksh That did nothing I'm afraid

Comment: Can you resolve the error in the demo above so we can actually see the thing in action?

Comment: @nicwillu oops missread the code you could try to add in the `done` function in the block with the `mode==...` a new mode there the interval is cleared or the `tick++` isn't called so the images won't be incrementes anymore

Comment: @Mucksh Could you provide an example? :)